# Transform panel. Quaternion mode. What is the 4L button good for?

Tags: modeling

When you switch the rotation mode to Quaternion in the Transform panel, then you will have four values available. W, X, Y and Z. That's a quaternion, which prevents gimbal lock.

Switching to quaternions also reveals a button called 4L. What it does is to show or hide the lock behind value W. The description of this button is rather cryptic. And i cannot figure out what is meant.

So what is this button good for?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out. A quaternion is made of three axis x, y and z. And the value W, which is a calculated value. Normally this calculated value has no lock since it is a mathematical calculated value. It can be used to retrieve the actual rotation around the defined angle.

The 4L button simply allows you to reveal a lock at the W value too. And that's already it for the functionality of this 4L button.